# Why doesn't Integer objects Unbox when compared with `==` operator?

Tags: java, integer, wrapper, unboxing

Because sometimes it gets confusing.
Lets say:

```
Integer start=new Integer(10);
Integer mid=new Integer(10);
Integer end=new Integer(20);
System.out.println(start<end); // gives true
System.out.println(start!=end); // gives true
System.out.println(start==mid); // BAM! gives false
```

The Objects get unboxed in the first two lines, but the last one works the same way, it compares the reference. Shouldn't it Unbox the objects too. This would only make things simpler(it would, right?), or am I missing something here ?

Comment: I don't think the second one is unboxing either.  It's doing a reference inequality test I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 1.4, there was no unboxing and so you could write

```
Integer x = new Integer (10);
Integer y = new Integer (10);
System.out.println(x == y); // false;
System.out.println(x != y); // true;
```

And so when they added boxing, and unboxing this code had to work the same way, otherwise they would break backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The `!=` comparison gives `true` by coincidence (i.e. not because of the fact that `10 != 2`) For example, it produces `true` when you compare `start != mid` ([demo](http://ideone.com/uZTqvE)). The reason is that `start` and `mid` are not unboxed for comparison.

The reason why there is no unboxing is that Java defines semantics for `==` and `!=` on reference objects in a way independent of the type of the type of the object, and does not provide for overriding these operators. The existing definition compares references to see if they refer to the same object; that is the semantics followed by `==` and `!=` in your code example.

Answer (score 0):

You simply compare the references of your Integer-Objects as [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223907/why-doesnt-integer-objects-unbox-when-compared-with-operator/25223935#25223935) already described.

For comparing Integers correctly, you need to use `equals`, `compareTo`, or cast them to their primitives with `(int)` or calling `intValue()` on at least on Integer-Object, which you compare.

Answer (score 0):

You have three different object references (start, mid and end) with three different String objects in the heap. Two of them with the same value.
If you assign one reference to another the comparison is true (two reference objects with the same String object in the heap)

```
Integer start = new Integer(10);
Integer mid = start; 
System.out.println(start==mid); //  gives true
```